# How to create a constant array to be filled with enumerations in Microsoft Visual Studio C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, structure, enumeration

this is my code:

```
//first enumeration declaration
public enum Te1 {  
  e1_e1  = 5,
  e1_e2 = 19
}  

//second enumeration declaration
public enum Te2 {
  e2_e1 = 6,
  e2_e2 = 7,
}  

//structure for holding both enumeration values
public struct Tu1 {
  Te1 e1;
  Te2 e2;
}  

//create and fill an array of structures with enumeration values (this codeline generates an error)
var u1 = new Tu1[] {
  { Te1.e1_e1, Te2.e2_e1 }
};
```

Create and fill an array of structures with enumeration values (this codeline generates an error)
Where do I go wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Henk

Comment: Is `Te2.e2_e1` a `Tu1`?

Comment: Does `var u1 = new Tu1 {
  { e1 = Te1.e1_e1, e2 = Te2.e2_e1 }};` do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I think you strucct initialization syntax is incorrect. Instead of

```
  { Te1.e1_e1, Te2.e2_e1 }
};
```

Try

```
  new Tu1{ e1 = Te1.e1_e1, e2 = Te2.e2_e1 }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First, when initial a struct object, you need to use keyword `new` and specify the field or property name.

```
new Tu1{ e1 = Te1.e1_e1, e2 = Te2.e2_e1 }
```

Besides, in the struct you define, `e1` and `e2` are both private fields. You can't assign value to them directly.

So, try to add access modifier `public` for the fields, or define corresponding properties (this will be better).

```
public struct Tu1
{
    public Te1 e1 { get; set; }
    public Te2 e2 { get; set; }
}
```

You can also define a constructor for the struct as followed.

```
public struct Tu1
{
    Te1 e1;
    Te2 e2;
    public Tu1(Te1 te1, Te2 te2)
    {
        e1 = te1;
        e2 = te2;
    }
}
```

And create the array as followed.

```
var u1 = new Tu1[] {
    new Tu1(Te1.e1_e1, Te2.e2_e1)
};
```

Comment: Hi, Kyle Wang solved my problem. I last programmed C# 2 years agoo and was forgotten about structures may have a constructor... Thanks everybody.

Comment: @HenkvW If this reply helped you, maybe you can mark it as the answer.